# Function in R for this formula

Tags: r

I'm struggling to figure out how to use normal functions inside the function I'm making in RStudio.
Also, I'm still in the process of understanding the iteration.

For example, how can I solve the problem attached?

I can come with the formula like below

```
x[4] = abs(x[2] - x[3]) / 2
```

But I don't know how to use for loop and function together at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```r
func <- function(x, n) {
  for(i in 4:n) {
    x[i] <- x[i-1] + abs(x[i-2] - x[i-3])
  }
  return(x[n])
}
```

Resulting in:

```r
func(x = c(3, 5, 6), n = 10)
#> [1] 17
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'll run and see which part I need to understand more!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive approach:

```
foo <- function(x, xd) {
    if (x %in% names(xd)) {
        return(xd[[x]])
    }
    foo(x-1, xd) + (abs(foo(x-2, xd) - foo(x-3, xd)) / 2)
}
example = list(`1` = 3, `2` = 1, `3` = 10)
foo(4, example)
```

Update: using tail recursion (?)

```
foo <- function(g, x1, x2, x3, i=4) {
    x = x1 + (abs(x2 - x3)/2)
    if (i == g) {
        return(x)
    }
    return(foo(g, x, x1, x2, i+1))
}

foo(4, 10, 1, 3) # 11
```

Comment: I appreciate your input! I'll run and see which part I need to understand more!

Comment: This recursion is not good. Very inefficient. Notice how depending on the depth, you will be computing the same quantities multiple times. ie `foo(x-1)` will compute `foo(x-2)` which will compute `foo(x-3)`. Yet you are also still computing `f(x-2)` separately and `foo(x-3)` separately.  You should consider using a tail recursion, or even save the results in a local memory and reuse the results. Otherwise

Comment: @Onyambu thanks for the feedback! I was considering saving intermediate results, but didn't want to overcomplicate things for OP. I'll update the function now though :--)

Comment: I would encourage you to use the `local` function in R, or you could use `tail recursion`

Comment: hmmm I added what (i think?) it should look like, using tail recursion, though I'll admit I only just learned of this today. The examples I see online are a lot simpler. Unsure if I should add an accumulator variable @Onyambu

Comment: `fn <- function(n, x){
  if(n == 3) x[3]
  else fn(n-1, c(x[-1], x[3] + abs(x[2] - x[1])/2))
}` should do

Comment: then run `fn(4, c(3,1,10))` of course you could switch and use head recursion. or even swith the parameters around as you want. You could also return all the intermediate points. But at least each point is only evaluated once

Comment: ++1 for the tail recursion. Though you have each element of `x` as an input. instead of having one vector `x`. You could also do `fn <- function(x, n)Reduce(\(x,y) c(x[-1], x[3] + abs(x[2] - x[1])/2), seq(n-3),x)[3]`

Comment: I was just looking at if reduce could be used in this context haha! The `purrr` version though. My experience is that `tidyverse` functions are always slower than I imagined, and `reduce()` was looking for one - two inputs, and I had three (didn't think of putting them in a vector

Comment: Yes you can use `purrr::reduce`. The syntax is the same. ie `reduce(seq_len(n-3), ~c(.x[-1], .x[3] + abs(.x[2] - .x[1])/2), .init = c(3,1,10))[3]`

Comment: Probably you should consider updating and adding the best version of your solution

Comment: actually @Onyambu would you like to post an answer? It feels wrong, it having my name under the answer when it was your (excellent!) code

Comment: You can write an answer, and I'll upvote it as a way of saying thanks! :-)